# Does using DiffUtil when all items change completely make sense?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm making an app which uses RecyclerView to display lists of popular apps or songs (never combined). There are two actions: first updates list just a little bit (adds or removes few items), so using DiffUtil seems a good idea here. But in the second case, all items are changed. Sometimes it's only structural change (when I switch between different apps lists) and sometimes also item types are different (when I switch from apps to songs). I'm new to Android and I'm not sure weather I should use DiffUtil in these cases as well or it only causes unnecessary comparison between lists that are different anyway. And if so, should I use method like notifyDataSetChanged() or just create and set new Adapter with new data?

I've read documentation and some articles on the subject, but I'm still confused, so I'll be very grateful for advice on how to best handle this issue.

Comment: Using `DiffUtil` only make sense for small range changes. You do not need to make `DiffUtil` unneeded calculation if all data is changed.
Secondly, setting new adapter or calling `notifyDataSetChange` depends on your case. If it a completely different views then create new adapter and use it. Otherwise, set new data to the existed adapter and call `notifyDataSetChange`.